# Flattening Nested Scalaz Validations

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm fairly new to scalaz and I've started out with validations.

I have some validation functions of the form:

```
def validateXyz(...): ValidationNEL[String, String] = ...
```

I'm then using the applicative style to combine multiple validations and then call another function that also returns a validation:

```
(validateXyz(...) |@| validateAbc(...)) { (first, second) =>
   otherFunction(first, second)
}
```

where,

```
def otherFunction(first: String, second: String): ValidationNEL[String, String] = ...
```

However, when calling the above the resulting type is:

```
val result: ValidationNEL[String, ValidationNEL[String, String]] = ...
```

I can unpack this by calling fold on the result with two functions, the first which just propagates the NEL as a fail and the second which just propagates its argument:

```
def propagateF(result: NonEmptyList[String]): ValidationNEL[String, String] = result.fail
def propagateV(result: ValidationNEL[String, String]) = result

result.fold(propagateF, propagateV)
// result type: ValidationNEL[String, String]
```

This works and returns the correct types and results. However it doesn't feel like the correct solution so I must be missing something. What do I need to do to avoid this horrible fold at the end?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for here is monadic `join`.

The thing is that `Validation` itself is not really a monad, since the error side carries a `Semigroup` structure that cannot be preserved by `Monad`. But you can always drop down into the `Either` monad if you need to. This functionality is provided by `flatMap`.

```
(validateXyz(...) |@| validateAbc(...))(otherFunction).flatMap(x => x)
```

If you have an error on the outside, the result will be that error. If you have an error inside of a success, the result will be the inner error. Otherwise the result will be a success. Note the impossibility of having an error *both on the inside and outside*. This is why you have to use `Applicative` rather than `Monad` if you want to combine errors.

Comment: Absolutely amazing. This got me out of a real hole.

Comment: Any answer involving scalaz really needs to include imports to allow it to compile. Very frustrating if not included.